# Read commited isolation level

Tags: transactions, isolation

I have a question regarding read commited isolation. I know that it prevent from dirty reads and dirty writes but how it behave in situation like this in photo (assume that both transaction have read commited isolation level). Which value will see user two after user one commited his changes ?[image]

Comment: This Question might be more appropriate for dba.StackExchange.com.